# Issues when printing my JFrame

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm making a program for the company of a friend and I need to print a `JFrame` with a bunch of `JLabel` and stuff. No problems until here.

When I print my `JFrame` I have some JLabels that get automatically concatenate for some unknown reasons. When I display my `JFrame` just before printing I have no problems with display features like auto concatenation.
But when I print it, on the paper it is concatenated ...
I've been looking on the internet for hours trying to figure it out but found nothing.

I'll share the code that I use to print since it seems that the problem comes from here :

```
public void test() throws PrinterException
    {
        PageFormat format = new PageFormat();

        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setImageableArea(0.0,0.0,Double.MAX_VALUE,Double.MAX_VALUE);
        format.setPaper(paper);

        PrinterJob jb = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        format = jb.validatePage(format);
        jb.setPrintable(this, format);
        jb.print();
        dispose();
    }

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
            throws PrinterException 
    {
        if (page > 0)
            {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

        Dimension dim = this.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

        double pHeight = pf.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = pf.getImageableWidth();

        double pXStart = pf.getImageableX();
        double pYStart = pf.getImageableY();

        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
        g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
        this.paint(g2);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

By the way I started Java this year and I'm quite a newbie :)

Comment: If this can help, this problem only occurs when all characters used in the `JLabel` are in capital letters.

Comment: Help please, I still haven't figured out how to fix this !

Comment: Does anybody have any idea ? Please :(